# xpages application layout login node: way to stay on the same page once logged in?

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I have an application that uses the application layout.  The login node was added to the application layout (xe:loginTreeNode), in the utility links.

The control works, but when a user logs in, he is redirected to the application's home page.  Is there a way to log in and stay on the current page?

Comment: Try this http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Xpages%20Dojo%20Login%20Custom%20Control. Redirect URL can be always computed to the current page.

Comment: we are not using a lofin form, so can't really use that one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do this is to use a cookie to remember the page that they are on prior to pushing the login button. You can't use any scoped variables or managed beans since those will lost when you logout.

Then in your login page, check the cookie for a value and redirect to that page, otherwise if the cookie is null take them to the home page.  You can write and read cookies using clientside JS.

---

Since you are not using a custom login form, another idea would be to use a Basic Node instead. The basic node has a clientside onClick event. In here you could put code similar to this:

```
var currentPage = [code to obtain the current page];
location.href="/yourFolder/yourDatabase.nsf?logout&redirectTo=/yourFolder/yourDatabase.nsf/currentPage";
```

I am not all that confident that this will work but it is worth a try.

Comment: Steve, all I have when logging in is a dialog with the user name and password fields.  No login form is in place, so that takes care of the cookie thing...   I wish there were a redirectto property to that login node...

Answer (score 2):

Implementation of `xe:loginTreeNode`:

```
@Override
public String getHref() {
    String href = super.getHref();
    if(StringUtil.isNotEmpty(href)) {
        return href;
    }
    boolean logged = isLoggedIn();
    String command = "";
    FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();

    if(logged && StringUtil.equals(ctx.getExternalContext().getAuthType(), "Domino")) //$NON-NLS-1$
    {
        command = "?logout"; // $NON-NLS-1$
    }
    else
    {
        command = /*logged ? "/?logout" :*/ "/?opendatabase&login"; // $NON-NLS-1$
    }
    href = ctx.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath() + command;
    return href;
}
```

Simply said: if you want it NOT to redirect, just use basicTreeNode, take any URL and append "?login" to it.